# How to get a Asus Transformer book T100TA-C1-QR working on Ubuntu

Tags: asus

so I bought me this tablet/laptop because I wanna use it for school work and it came with Windows 8.1. I'm not a fan of Windows and I wanna to use Linux on it. so I Google it and founded to way but I one problem so far is that I can't get the WiFi working on it. I used Ubuntu 14.04.4 64-bit and also used Rufus to make the bootable USB. I Google the WiFi problem but they said they got it working but not showing or tell you how they got it working. I put two pictures down showing you the tablet/laptop specs. if there is no way to get Ubuntu run with the WiFi working I might just return it at my local Walmart because I already use Ubuntu 14.04.4 on my Laptop that I'm on right now but I wanna that tablet/laptop because it was small and easy to carry around. Or is there any other Linux OS out there that worked on this tablet/laptop out of the box it doesn't really have to be Ubuntu based it can be Arch based or other based Linux. Thank You[image: Device Manager][image: Windows System]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm using Ubuntu on a T100TA right now, and it's working quite well.

These [instructions](http://www.jfwhome.com/2016/01/04/latest-steps-to-install-ubuntu-on-the-asus-t100ta/) helped so much. Look at [this Google Plus page](https://plus.google.com/communities/117853703024346186936) also.

It's important to install a proper kernel. I'm using 4.4 from [this Google group, there you can find all kinds of helpful files are here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B9C1WK1FQhjfcXNrbzN6djQzajg&usp=sharing#list)